# Weird UISwitch behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiswitch

I'm working on a smart home app where the user can toggle a device.

If the device isnt connected its possibly dangerous to flip the switch, so in this case I flip the switch back with `switch.isOn = false` and display an alert.

Sometimes the switch is frozen state where the ui displays it **half On** (circle is left , background is blue) and the properties are showing its turned off.

Is there any known workaround for this? Or am I the only one who encountes this error?

Google doesnt show an direct way to solve this

```
public class MyUIController: UIViewController{
...
weak var switch:UISwitch!

@IBAction
public func toggle(sender:Any){
    if (device.isConnected){
        device.sendUpdate(switch.isOn)
    }else{
        switch.isOn = false
    }
}
...
}
```

Comment: You should show your code, but why not disable the switch if the device isn't connected?  That is much better UX than letting the user do something and then telling them that they can't

Comment: Okay there is a littel timeout between disconnecting the device and the actual update of the device

Comment: Ok.  You should still disable the switch.  Edit your question to show your code. Even if you do detect that the device is disconnected and display an alert there is no need to turn the switch off until the alert is dismissed. This will probably fix your issue

Comment: Ill try that out tomorrow ,ty

Comment: Are you accessing `isOn` from somewhere else? is `isConnected` waiting for some server response (e.g. synchronous calling?) What kind of alert are you displaying? Is it possible that you are taking a screenshot of your UI when displaying the alert? Are you manually removing animations somewhere (e.g. `view.layer.removeAnimations()`)?

Comment: okay now ive tested this intensive with and without threads , by turning the switch off after the alert got dismissed ( usability unit leader kicked my face for that ), with an delay, nothing worked

Answer (score -1):

You should disable the switch when the device isn't connected to provide a better user experience. If you need to toggle the state of the switch after the user toggles it, wait until the animation is finished. This will fix the freezing and strange graphic effects.

```
switch.isEnabled = false
```

Comment: i think you are on the right way but i dont see how i can run my ibaction after the animation or the time difference from the userclick till the event arrives may be less than the animation(async) as paulw11 suggests ill try your ideas out tomorrow